# For loop inside innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Good day! I want to ask you a question, how can I make this work?

```
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "<h3 align='center'><u>CL "+CLE+"</u></h3>"+ for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {"<h1>hi</h1> " }+";
```

Because my idea was to print a data X times, and I don't want to have to copy and paste the same code, I tried the script above and it didn't work, I also read something about ternary operators, but I don't know if it works here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create the list, and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to combine them into one string:

```js
const CLE = 2;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 
  `<h3 align='center'><u>CL ${CLE}</u></h3>` +
  Array.from({length:9}, () => "<h1>hi</h1>").join('');
```

```html
<div id="demo2"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the `for` won't return anything, you can use array methods:

```
var arr = Array(9).fill(0);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "<h3 align='center'><u>CL "+CLE+"</u></h3>"+ 
    arr.map(_ => "<h1>hi</h1> ").join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template literal paired with `map` to get this done like below:

```js
const CLE = 'test';

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = `<h3 align='center'><u>CL ${CLE}</u></h3>${[...Array(9)].map((n) => "<h1>hi</h1> ").join(' ')}`;
```

```html
<div id="demo2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

No, this won't work. `for` is no ternary operator in JS.

### Not so short Answer

There are ways to solve your problem:

1. If you just want to repeat the string, you can use `String.prototype.repeat(n)`

   ```js
   "<h1>hi</h1> ".repeat(9)
   ```
2. A multiline solution would be

   ```js
   var str = "" // Whatever was before the loop
   for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
     str += "<h1>hi</h1> ";
   }
   str += "" // Whatever

   // To better work with the DOM, set the innerHTML as few times as you can
   element.innerHTML = str
   ```
3. A one-liner, for one-line addicteds:

   ```js
   element.innerHTML = "" + (Array.from({ length: 9 }).fill("<h1>hi</h1>").join(" ")) + ""
   ```

Answer (score 1):

simply use a [string repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

```
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "<h3 align='center'><u>CL " 
                                           + CLE 
                                           + "</u></h3>"
                                           + "<h1>hi</h1> ".repeat(9);
```